# WordPress search not working properly

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a recipe website and search option in it. Now i have recipe name **CAKE** and when i search **CAKES** then its not showing result. Its fine with **CAKE** or **CAK** . I want result with LIKE query. Please help me out.

Here is my custom search args code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'recipes', 's' => $_GET['s'] );
$myposts    = get_posts( $args );
if ( empty( $myposts ) ) {
    echo 'No results found in Recipe!';
} else { ?>
//show recipes
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

Comment: Which function use .??

Comment: if recipe is a category just use category taxonomy and pass cake to match , that will help you get the result. what you have done will try to match the post title and search key, do you think that should give you the post ?

Comment: i am using get_posts() function

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu recipes is post type and i am using get_posts() function with my given args.

Comment: @SandeepRathore post your function here as well as let us know what "cake" is ? a post name, a taxonomy name or ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu i updated function in question.

Comment: if you have a post name that contains words like cake and query string contains `?s=cake` ,  I think your code should work .

Comment: Yes i know that bro but i want it to work as LIKE query so when i search "CAKES" then it should also show result of cake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'recipes','s' => $_GET['s']);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        //whatever you want to do with each post
    }
} else {
     // no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many research i found an alternate. I change plural terms into singular with some php manipulation. Here is i am sharing it.

```
$str = $_GET['s'];
$result = rtrim($str, 's');
$result_sing = str_pad($result, strlen($str) - 1, 's');
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'post_type' => 'recipes', 
's' => $result_sing,
);
```